# Allure gradle conflict using custom gradle wrapper

Tags: gradle, conflict, allure

At our firm we're supposed to user proprietary gradle wrapper and I think this issue is related to it.

This is the part of my `build.gradle` related to Allure:

```
 apply plugin: 'io.qameta.allure'

 buildscript {
    dependencies {
        ...
        classpath 'io.qameta.allure:allure-gradle:2.5'
    }
}

allure {
    autoconfigure = true
    version = '2.5.0'
}
```

And here is the error I get every time I'm trying to build project:

> Unable to find method
>   'org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskOutputs.files([Ljava/lang/Object;)Lorg/gradle/api/tasks/TaskOutputFilePropertyBuilder;'.
>   Possible causes for this unexpected error include:
>
> - Gradle's
>     dependency cache may be corrupt (this sometimes occurs after a network
>     connection timeout.) Re-download dependencies and sync project
>     (requires network)
> - The state of a Gradle build process
>     (daemon) may be corrupt. Stopping all Gradle daemons may solve this
>     problem. Stop Gradle build processes (requires restart)
> - Your
>     project may be using a third-party plugin which is not compatible with
>     the other plugins in the project or the version of Gradle requested by
>     the project.
>
> In the case of corrupt Gradle processes, you can
>   also try closing the IDE and then killing all Java processes.

Is there any workaround for that?

Answer (score 0):

I think the plugin resolution should be:

```
 buildscript {
     dependencies {
         classpath 'io.qameta.allure:allure-gradle:2.5'
     }
 }

 apply plugin: 'io.qameta.allure'

 // apply to project
 allure {
    autoconfigure = true
    version = '2.5.0'
 }
```